# ExtenderControlProperty two-way binding?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am creating a AJAX Extender Control and would like to pass a value back to the server on post-back.

Are ExtenderControlProperties two-way?  If not, is there any way of making them two way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the ExtenderControlProperties are not two-way.  I solved this using a hiddenfield.  This is how I implemented it.

I put this In the extender

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenFieldId = ClientID + "_HiddenValue";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(HiddenFieldId, "");
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    [ExtenderControlProperty]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string HiddenFieldId
    {
        get { return GetPropertyValue("HiddenFieldId", ""); }
        set { SetPropertyValue("HiddenFieldId", value); }
    }

    public string HiddenFieldValue
    {
        get { return Page.Request.Form[HiddenFieldId]; }
    }
```

and this in the behaviour

```
//In the prototype
get_HiddenFieldId: function() {
    return this._hiddenFieldId;
},
set_HiddenFieldId: function(value) {
    this._hiddenFieldId = value;
},

//In the initialisation
this._hiddenFieldId = null;  

//In my method when I want to set the hidden value.
document.getElementById(this._hiddenFieldId).value = valueToSet;
```